# Trying to create login with cookies

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm try to get cookies on to a browser. It's giving me parameter 1 error and parameter 3. This code works elsewhere on my site but not here. Can someone help me?

```
if ((!isset($_POST["uname"])) || (!isset($_POST["password"])))  
{
  header ("Location: wddnt/clients/'. $tattoo_extern_acct . '/index.html");
  exit;
}

$userpass = md5($_POST['password']);
@$db = mysqli_connect("$dbc_ser", "$dbc_usr", "$dbc_pwd", "$dbc_db"); 
$sql = "SELECT id, name, company, job_title, cell_num, office_num, office_email,
               login_right, first_run, attempts, locked_out FROM login 
         WHERE email = '".$_POST["email"]."' 
         AND   password = PASSWORD('$userpass')";

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   echo 'Cannot connect to database: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
   $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

   while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
   {
     $id = stripslashes($info['id_files']);
     $u_acct = stripslashes($info['uname']);
     $name = stripslashes($info['name']);
     $job_title = stripslashes($info['job_title']);
     $location = stripslashes($info['company']);
     $cell_num = stripslashes($info['cell_num']);
     $office_num = stripslashes($info['office_num']);
     $office_email = stripslashes($info['office_email']);
     $login_right = stripslashes($info['login_right']);
     $first_run = stripslashes($info['first_run']);
     $attempts = stripslashes($info['attempts']);
     $locked_out = stripslashes($info['locked_out']);
     $land_page = stripslashes($info['land_page']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the entire error into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging some of the individual variables. What is in $sql, for example? Is it correct?

Is the "Cannot connect" clause executed, or does it get to the query and fail there? (I am not sure what "parameter 1 error and parameter 3" means).

Don't forget to escape the 'email' value by the way - this code has an SQL injection hole.

Answer (score 0):

> header ("Location: wddnt/clients/'. $tattoo_extern_acct . '/index.html");

This is not going to work the way you expect.

> $sql = "SELECT id, name, company, job_title, cell_num, office_num, office_email,
>                 login_right, first_run, attempts, locked_out FROM login 
>           WHERE email = '".$_POST["email"]."'

You need to read up on SQL injection.

> while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

You allow multiple accounts with the same email address / password?????

> It's giving me parameter 1 error and parameter 3

Couldn't you post the *actual* error message you get?

> $id = stripslashes($info['id_files']);

WTF? Smartquotes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand your question but the last time i checked anyone who wants to use cookies uses the $_COOKIE global variable, either for setting them or accessing them. $_POST is made to get  stuffs from forms, not cookies.
Please check the manual for more details about $_COOKIE
Regards